# Concrete5 contact form (hundreds of emails)

Tags: php, forms, content-management-system, concrete5

Alright so im very new to concrete5, im working on a site and there is a profile page template  ive created a contact form (ill be using php). The problem is that their are alot of profiles and each has its own unique email. I am very confused as to what i need to research or do to find a somewhat simple solution to *being able to change the email from concrete5 edit page to what the profile email is*.

maybe this doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Is this for sending private messages to other users?

Comment: tofraser has a good point. If this is for logged in users to message other users, then you can use the private messaging feature. Otherwise, you should probably add a "contact email" attribute to the user (or the page, if these are all separate pages), and then override the contact form controller, which isn't trivial, but not super difficult.